# How can I refactor this code into multi-thread version?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

There is a loop which takes quite a long time and I'm considering refactoring this code into multi-thread version. And here is the model.

```
   Photon photon;
    for (int i=0;i<1000000;++i){
         func(){
          photon.lanuch(args...){
          // do something  
          }
      }
    }
```

I have to call this function a thousand and thousand times.So I was wondering how can I create some threads to run this function at the some time.
But the photon have to be individual every single time.
the index i can be converted to this:

```
 atomic<int> i{0};
    while(i<1000000){
          func(){
              photon.lanuch(args...){
              // do something  
             ++i;
               }
          }
    }
```

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but there's no point in using `register` these days. Compilers are free to ignore it, and they always will. They're much better at identifying hot spots than you or I.

Comment: `register int i=0;` Where did you even get that idea? Did you read a C book from the 80s? 0.o

Comment: Do you want to use C++11 threads or is OpenMP also ok?

Comment: emmmm... this code is rewrote from C code...so I keep register....

Comment: C++11 threads...thanks

Comment: If you post a simple example of your loop that we can compile, we can assist you in making it multi-threaded.

Comment: What do you mean by _"photon have to be individual every single time"_? Is `photon.lanuch()` supposed to be thread-safe?

Comment: Re: "rewrote from C code... so I keep register" -- `register` In C is just as pointless these days as it is in C++. Really: it doesn't do anything any more.

Comment: @PeteBecker We don't know. Given it handles photons maybe God wrote the C code at the dawn of time when magic was in the world and `register` meant something (e.g. early 90s).

Comment: I strongly suggest you have a look into Intel Thread Building Blocks (TBB) library. It provides very convenient micro-parallelization using C++11 lambda notation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With threading you have to pay attention to object lifetime and sharing far more than normal.

But the basic solution is

```
void do_tasks( std::size_t count, std::function<void( std::size_t start, std::size_t finish )> task ) {
  auto thread_count = std::thread::hardware_concurrency();
  if (thread_count <= 0) thread_count = 1;

  std::vector<std::future<void>> threads( thread_count-1 );

  auto get_task = [=](std::size_t index) {
    auto start = count * index / thread_count;
    auto finish = count * (index+1) / thread_count;
    // std::cout << "from " << start << " to " << finish << "\n";
    return [task, start, finish]{ task(start, finish); };
  };
  for( auto& thread : threads ) {
    auto index = &thread-threads.data();
    thread = std::async( std::launch::async, get_task(index) );
  }
  get_task( threads.size() )();
  for (auto& thread : threads) {
    thread.get();
  }
}
```

This is a little multi threading library.

You use it like this:

```
do_tasks( 100, [&](size_t start, size_t finish) {
  // do subtasks starting at index start, up to and not including finish
});
```

There are other more complex threading libraries, but writing a small half-decent one isn't hard so I did it.

To be explicit:

```
Photon photon;
do_tasks( 1000000, [&](size_t start, size_t finish) {
  for (int i = start; i < finish; ++i) {
    photon.lanuch(args...){
  }
});
```

but you'll have to be extremely careful making sure there is no unsafe data sharing between the threads, and you aren't just blocking each thread on a common mutex.

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0c4826faf3dbf510)

Answer (score 2):

A awful lot depends on how and to what extent `photon.launch()` can be parallelised.

The code below divides a range into (approximately) equal segments and then executes each segment in a separate thread.

As stated whether that helps will depend on how much of `photon.launch()` can be done in parallel. If it spends most of its time modifying a shared state and essentially has the form:

```
    void launch(int index){
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard{m};
        //.....
    }
```

Where `m` is a member of `Photon` then little if anything will be gained.
If (at the other extreme) the individual calls to `launch` never contend for the same data then it can be parallelised up to the number of cores the system can provide.

```
#include <thread>
#include <vector>

class Photon {
    public: 
    void launch(int index){
        //... what goes here matters a lot...
    }
};


void photon_launch(Photon& photon,int from,int to){
    for(auto i=from;i<=to;++i){
        photon.launch(i);
    }
}


int main() {
    const size_t loop_count=100000;//How big is the loop?
    const size_t thread_count=4;//How many threads can we utilize?
    std::vector< std::thread > threads;

    Photon photon;
    int from=1;
    for(size_t i=1;i<=thread_count;++i){

        //If loop_count isn't divisible by thread_count evens out the remainder.        
        int to=(loop_count*i)/thread_count;
        threads.emplace_back(photon_launch,std::ref(photon),from,to);
        from=to+1;
    }

    //Now the threads are launched we block until they all finish.
    //If we don't the program may (will?) finish before the threads.
    for(auto& curr : threads){
        curr.join();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @SimonCqk The important question is about writes to shared data in your thread. I'm speculating but if it's some ray-tracing application you might not need to lock data while tracing but should lock while writing to the viewport . The trick in such cases is to minimise the time threads spend under that lock.